# How could I select 'this' and something else at once with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have a click handler:

```
$('some_selector').click(function(){

});
```

Inside of the handler, I can use `$(this)` to select the element that was clicked.

Is there a way to select the clicked element and something else in 1 statement?  Perhaps, something like:

```
$(this, 'some_other_selector')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use .add()

http://api.jquery.com/add/

example

```
$('some_selector').click(function(){
    $(this).add('some_other_selector');
});
```

Comment: yeah `this` before the `click()` trigger will certainly work :D

Comment: You had a good answer the first time.  This right now, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.add()` you can also do:

```
$([ this, $(selector)[0] ])
```

I would prefer `.add()` since the above method is limited to selectors that only return 1 element.

It works because you can pass an array of `DOMElement`s to jQuery.